# How to fix the height / width ratio in a constraint layout with a bg image?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, vector, android-constraintlayout

I've created a TextView inside a Constraint Layout to be displayed at the top right corner in my activity. The TextView gets his value from a JSON, so the length of it isn't fixed, the problem is the design of my background:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:padding="@dimen/default_padding">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/age"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_agebg"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_big"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_small"

    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="10000000.000 BC"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/default_padding"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The result of this code is visible below:
[image]

My background contains a star in a vector format and also the button borders, so every time the width / height ratio gets out of a certain ratio (with long or short textes), the star is streched or flattened. Can I keep the aspect ratio of the background / layout within fixed limits or a prefixed ratio?

Answer (score 0):

You can use separate drawables for star and the text background and then try to achieve the UI as expected, try following which could help,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="@dimen/default_padding">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/age"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_big"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_small"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_small"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/padding_small">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="10000000.000 BC"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/default_padding"
            android:background="@color/colorRed"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/emptyView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W, 1:1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:background="@drawable/avtar"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/emptyView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W, 0.5:1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"/>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: this seems to be a good idea, what's the empty view for? And how would you proceed to get the border like I got in my background image?

Comment: Empty View is for adjusting TextView dynamically as per the width of the imageView. You can use drawable XML background to the TextView for the border.